# If statement - Variable order for null safety

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

Assume I want to check if the first element from a list is equal to "YES" or "NO".

```
dummy_method(List<String> myList) {
    if(myList.isEmpty()) {
        return null; 
    }
    String firstListValue = myList.get(0).getStringValue(); 
    // Should I do this: 
    if ("YES".equalsIgnoreCase(firstListValue)) {
        return firstListValue; 
    }
    // OR this: 
    if (firstListValue.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
        return firstListValue; 
    }
    // Do something else
}
```

In other words: Does the order of *if A equals B* versus *if B equals A* matter when I already have a null-check?

Comment: Always the first one to avoid null

Comment: In short: no, if you know both are not null then the order must not matter (i.e. per the contract of `equals()` `a.equals(b)` must have to be the same as `b.equals(a)`. However, your code doesn't do a null check on `firstListValue` and thus `"YES".equalsIgnoreCase(firstListValue)` is the safer option (you know that `"YES"` will not be null)

Comment: `String firstListValue = myList.get(0).getStringValue(); ` can throw `NullPointerException` as well.

Comment: "I already have a null-check" - where? You only check for an empty list but note that lists can contain null elements and even non-null elements can have null properties.

Comment: @JackFlamp where?

Comment: @JackFlamp try with `new LinkedList<String>(null)`  ;) - `isEmpty()` is _not_ a null check.

Comment: @JackFlamp Checking if the list is empty doesn't preclude the possibility that `myList.get(0)` returns null. Bring empty and containing null are two different things.

Comment: @khelwood yes you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It matters.

You have only checked if the list is non-empty. If the first element in the list is *null* then you will get a `NullPointerException` at

```
firstListValue.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")
```

But, if you can ensure all the elements (or at least the first element) in the list are non-null, then both the statements are equivalent.

Comment: Of course! Made the error of automatically assuming that since the list is not empty, the field would not be empty.

Answer (score 1):

For null safety you can use your first if like this:

```
if ("YES".equalsIgnoreCase(firstListValue)) {
    return firstListValue; 
}
```

because "YES" is hardcoded string and won't be null. Where as in 2nd approach, whenever the list element is null, you will get `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

This check will also throw `NullPointerException` if the list is null, so you can check both conditions

```
if(myList!=null && !myList.isEmpty())
```

And also need 'null' check for all values retrieved through 'get()' , because if list is empty or specified index is out of range 'get()' method will not throw 'NullpointerException', it will just return null

Comment: like people readily pointed out to me, `myList.get(0)` can also return null since List can contain null values. So `isEmpty` will not prevent the NPE on `myList.get(0).getStringValue()`

Comment: Yes need to check for elements retrieved by get()