# Null safety in streams with anyMatch

Tags: java, string, list, null, java-stream

This is a follow-up question to: "[If statement - variable order for null safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854147/if-statement-variable-order-for-null-safety/51854272#51854272)"

Assume I have a list of "Response"-objects. This includes a String value stating either "YES" or "NO".

If all the members answer "YES", then "YES" is returned. If at least one member answers "NO", then "NO" is returned.
In other words, if the list contains a mix of "YES" and "NO" responses, the answer is "NO". Otherwise, the answer is "YES". 
(Assuming "YES" and "NO" are the only options).

```
String dummy_method(List<Response> myList) {
    if(myList.isEmpty()) {
        return null; 
    }
    String firstResponseValue = myList.get(0).getYesOrNoValue(); 
    if ("NO".equalsIgnoreCase(firstResponseValue)) {
        return firstResponseValue; 
    }
    return myList.stream.anyMatch(response -> !response.getYesOrNoValue().equalsIgnoreCase(firstResponseValue)) ? "NO" : firstResponseValue;
}
```

Is there an "elegant" way to ensure null-safety in the last return statement:

```
return myList.stream.anyMatch(response -> !response.getYesOrNoValue().equalsIgnoreCase(firstResponseValue)) ? "NO" : firstResponseValue;
```

Such as with

```
if ("NO".equalsIgnoreCase(firstResponseValue))
```

Comment: What if you have mix of YES and nulls?

Comment: Why not simply invert .anyMatch(response -> !response.getYesOrNoValue().equalsIgnoreCase(firstResponseValue)) to : .anyMatch(response -> !firstResponseValue.equalsIgnoreCase(response.getYesOrNoValue()))

Comment: What is the meaning of null? You explained how to treat "YES" and "NO", but what if there is a null in the list?

Comment: The `null` should be treated as a "NO" like in the first check. I believe that's the problem, that it would currently throw an NPE.

Comment: @Druckles That check only answers the question for the first element. The code example is very complex compared to the text explanation, especially "assuming "YES" and "NO" are the only options". I would like to get a confirmation from northerner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following snippet:

```
String dummy_method(List<Response> myList){
    final boolean allMatch = myList.stream()
        .map(Response::getYesOrNoValue)
        .allMatch("YES"::equals);

    return allMatch ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```

The use of `allMatch` is the same as using an inverted `anyMatch`, I just prefer the former, but you aswell could it write like this:

```
String dummy_method(List<Response> myList){
    final boolean anyMatch = myList.stream()
        .map(Response::getYesOrNoValue)
        .map(value -> value == null ? "NO" : value) // since we compare to "NO", we have to convert nulls
        .anyMatch("NO"::equals); // changed from "YES" to "NO"

    return anyMatch ? "NO" : "YES"; // flipped "YES" and "NO"
}
```

Both are short circuiting, so they behave exactly the same.

---

You may just aswell use a *for-loop*:

```
String dummy_method(List<Response> myList){
    for(Response response : myList){
        if(response != null && "NO".equals(response.getYesOrNoValue())){
            return "NO";
        }
    }
    return "YES";
}
```

Which is probably the easiest and most readable solution of all three.

Comment: The OP is returning YES if the list has all `NO`s too

Comment: @user7 where is that written? I only can see that if all are `YES` then return `YES` else return `NO`

Comment: Oops.. You are right.. I missed the first `if` statement where we return if the first element is `NO`.

Comment: Can you not remove the null check in the `allMatch` case? `"YES".equals(null)` will also return false, so you can shorten the stream pipeline. maybe even inline the `map`: `myList.stream().allMatch(response -> "YES".equals(response.getYesOrNoValue()))`

Comment: @MalteHartwig you're right, I've removed those. Also the inlining depends on your codestyle, I prefer the former as it is more readable IMO, but the latter will work the same

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem properly, `getYesOrNoValue` may return `null`. So to answer your question directly, just default the firstResponseValue to `"NO"` if it's `null`.

```
String dummy_method(List<Response> myList) {
    if (myList.isEmpty()) {
        return null; 
    }

    String firstResponseValue = Optional.ofNullable(myList.get(0).getYesOrNoValue())
            .orElse("NO");
    if ("NO".equalsIgnoreCase(firstResponseValue)) {
        return firstResponseValue; 
    }

    return myList.stream()
        .anyMatch(response -> !firstResponseValue.equalsIgnoreCase(response.getYesOrNoValue())
            ? "NO" : firstResponseValue;
}
```

But then you might as well call `!"YES".equalsIgnoreCase(...)` as that what it's essentially doing. And then you can pretty much discard `firstResponseValue` completely. And then you're at Lino's answer ;-)

---

Aaand another way to implement it with `findFirst`:

```
String dummy_method(List<Response> myList) {
    if (myList.isEmpty()) {
        return null; 
    }

    myList.stream()
        .map(Response::getYesOrNoValue)
        .map(Optional::ofNullable)
        .map(answer -> answer.orElse("NO"))
        .filter("NO"::equalsIgnoreCase)
        .findFirst().orElse("YES");
}
```

You could just as well replace those two `.map()`s with @Lino's `value -> value == null ? "NO" : value`. But then I'd have `getYesOrNoValue` return an `Optional<String>` which would cut out the second call to `map` anyway.